# Manipulating text file using batch script on windows

Tags: batch-file, token, tokenize

I am trying to accomplish the following: I have text file with following entries

```
XXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX

DATE TIME AM/PM  SIZE FILENAME NEWFILE.ERR

XXXX XXX XXXX
XXX XXXXXX XXX
```

I want to read the line with .ERR at the end and count the tokens of that line.

Please let me know how can this be achieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%# in ('Type "File.txt" ^| FINDSTR ".ERR$"') Do (
    Call Set "Line=%%#"
    FOR %%@ IN (%%#) DO (Call Set /A "Tokens+=1")
    GOTO :BREAK
)

:BREAK
Echo Line: %LINE%
Echo Toks: %TOKENS%

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: Hi Elektro, I do not understand ('Type "File.txt" ^| FINDSTR ".ERR$"')

Comment: the first command (type) prints the file, and the second command (Findstr) searchs the Regular Expression ".ERR$" and prints only the coincidences. don't forget to accept my answer if the problem is solved, thanks for comment.

Comment: Is it possible to break after reading the first line with .err at the end. How do you pass the tokens variable to the for loop

Comment: I get this error when I run my batch script                                                                 The system cannot find the drive specified. ??

Comment: change the "file.txt" to the name of your real file :P, the script runs good

Comment: I am using real file, but it still gets that message

Comment: You are using my script without editing, or you've edited/inserted in other script?, that custom modification need to be the problem and that's another question.

Comment: i am good now. Really appreciate your help. I will accept your answer